# HttpMessageConverter invalid EOF handling

Tags: java, spring, eof

How must a Spring `HttpMessageConverter` handle an invalid EOF when reading data? That is, how does the rest of Spring MVC expect a customer converter to signal a bad request in that case?

The signatures of the method to implement for reading data is

```
 T read(Class<? extends T> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
 throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException
```

So there are two choices for signalling that an invalid EOF was found:

1. Throw an `IOException` (which ought to be an `EOFException`).
2. Throw an `HttpMessageNotReadableException` (which might itself have an `EOFException` as its `cause()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second option is probably better as it is easier to translate that into response code 400. `IOException` is too general exception to make any special handling for it.

Spring's own `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is also [translating all `IOException`s into `HttpMessageNotReadableException`s](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java#L170-L177).

Comment: What Spring's own converter does is key: this shows what *they* think is the correct thing to do. Also, as I have discovered, the new (in Spring 3.2) MVC test framework treats an (uncaught) `EOFException` as a test failure, but an `HttpMessageNotReadable` is not a test failure.